# Gravity on a right rectangular prism?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, newtonian-gravity

Let's assume there is a right rectangular prism floating about in space, what would the gravity be like across its 6 flat surfaces? What gravity would you experience if you set foot on the rectangular prism's surface? Would it be the same as on Earth? Or would it be different the further along the surface you walk?

Let's assume that this right rectangular prism has a constant density and has a mass equal to Earth's. At any point on the surface of this prism, would gravity vary? That is, would it be an extreme variation than compared to one traveling across the surface of Earth? How extreme would this differential be?

Here's a rectangular prism with specific dimensions in mind.

[image: Rectangular Prism with dimensions]

Comment: Here are some related questions, but this question about the field itself is *new and not a duplicate*. [Could you stably orbit around a square (cubic) body? Would the orbit destabilize automatically if not corrected by input?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20925/12102) and also [Another way to evaluate the gravitational force from a uniform cube?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/26537/17869) This is a *very interesting question*, as will be the answer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely physic and not related to astronomy. See https://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually cross posted: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390377/what-would-gravity-be-like-on-the-surface-of-a-right-rectangular-prism

Comment: That's one heck of an aspect ratio!  150:90:6 .  Practically a sheet of paper.

Comment: Yes gravity would vary. So, yes it would be different to Earth, because the mass is distributed in a different(asymmetric) way.

Comment: If the aspect ratio was 1:4:9 then it might be a monolith from 2001: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolith_(Space_Odyssey)

Comment: Some fun with simple maths... The gravity depends on distance from the centre of mass. In this case the distance from the centre to the furthest point (one of the corners) is 8,767km. By comparison, the mean radius of the Earth is 6,371km, so the corner would experience the same gravity as a spaceship over 2000 km from Earth, i.e. you would "weigh" about 53% of your weight at the Earth's surface.

Comment: ... whereas if you were in the centre of the largest plain you would be only 300km from the centre of mass, and you would be utterly crushed by the gravity (you would experience 491 times your "surface" weight).